# Review queue comment filters

Tags: support, comments, review, review-stats, review-badges

I was working through the Review queue, both first posts and late answers and I came across the following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289000/how-to-use-jquery-validate-plugin-in-cakephp-form/8256018#comment18044818_8256018):

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! – Gabriel Santos 5 mins ago

I thought this was rather strange considering the user it was directed to join StackOverflow over 11 months ago and the comment was for an answer from Nov 24, 2011.

The description for the review queue includes the following for comments:

> **Comment** to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up existing comments.

This comment is not constructive and *in my opinion completely unnecessary*, not only that, but I have noticed that several of these types of comments have received upvotes.  I am not trying to pick on the user who posted the comment, but looking through their [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744255/gabriel-santos?tab=activity&sort=comments) they have quite a few comments which are similar in nature.

My question is are there any filters in place to prevent these types of comments from used in the awarding of the review badges or towards the count of actioned items?

Comment: well, that comment is gone now. which user was it for?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman The comment was posted on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8256018/426671), the answer was posted in 2011 but the "Welcome to Stack Overflow" was posted in 2012.  By adding a comment to something in the review queue, you can get credit for reviewing regardless of the content in the comment.  My question was is there anything in place to prevent completely nonsense comments from counting towards the review item?

Comment: ok, i did respond some in my answer to this (which i found while researching a different question). i know nothing about that specific question though. how is this handled in general? would nonsense comments be expected to be flagged & deleted normally (as this comment apparently was)?

Comment: oh, just to be specific... that user is still rep 1, so even if they'd been here for many months, it was probably their first interaction with the community, other than searching for answers (which they could have done anonymously anyways)...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an answer, or a comment :) Please advise.

However... is this really a problem? I do this as well, in a very particular case: first posts or late answers from low-rep individuals. Note that I didn't even look at join date - only at rep, since that's a better indication of how much interaction they've actually had with stackoverflow.

The 'first posts' review usually comes with a question or answer that is, to be generous, less than optimal. So i'm giving some negative feedback. I'll usually respond with a welcome, along with the negative feedback - that softens the blow a bit and is hopefully a bit more encouraging.

However, some of these posts are actually quite good, and already of an appropriate quality for the site. I suppose I could just do a 'No change needed', but I have often done a welcome message, just to give another initial positive feedback that as a new user, they have already started using the site correctly.

It's probably unnecessary, but didn't think it hurt anything.

So... at least in my case, that is why I post similar comments, in constrained cases.